# Cant figure out Java find for an "abstract path"

Tags: java, file

I am working in `eclipse` trying to create a file.

This is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Local Admin\Desktop\1.txt");
```

I copied the path I am using directly from the properties of the file but I keep getting the error

> Invalid escape sequences.

I tried adding an extra "\" in front of each "\" but that didn't fix anything.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try replace each "\" with "/".

Comment: Or, replace "\" with "\\"

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Local Admin\\Desktop\\1.txt");
```

Or:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Local Admin/Desktop/1.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\" by either "\\" or "/".

Try this.

```
File file=new File("C:/Java/hello.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the path of the file in a string variable and passing that string variable.Use "\\"  if "\" doesn't works.

```
String filePath="your path";
File file=new File(filePath);
```